# Logging/Identifying Visitors from a Specific Campaign

Tags: html, google-analytics, seo, visitor-statistic

So hopefully this post is correctly labelled. I am looking for a way to track the response to a campaign via a specific URL or the like. Basically, I'd like to track the traffic that accumulates from both online ads AND print ads for a specific campaign. How would I go about this? I am able to provide a specialized link such as www.mysite.com/campaign - however I'd like this to display the same webpage that would be seen if just www.mysite.com - only with unique tracking statistics that would allow me to see firsthand, the response to that specific campaign.

Would a redirect with a specialized analytics code work? Would a particular PHP code do the trick? Will a redirect affect SEO? Would I be better off duplicating www.mysite.com and simply throwing analytics on the www.mysite.com/campaign page?

Forgive me if this is a simple task, I'd just like to know the proper, most effective route to take.

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Comment: Thank you. The problem with that would be Print Ads. I'd like to know who has accessed my site via a certain URL - but still have that URL display my index page. Would a simple redirect page with an analytics code suffice? If so, would this punish me SEO-wise?

Answer (score 0):

**do this:**

use the link provided by Eike

paste the tracking URL with GA code

no, it won't affect SEO